# NodeJS winston logging large number of writes bogs down

Tags: node.js, winston

Node JS - 12.7
Winston - 1.0.1

I am struggling with trying to generate "fake" log files representing many "devices". Basically I am going to use the data for testing and visualization in Kibana.

I set my Winston up to log to file as so:

```
var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
        filename: 'logs/dsm.log'
    })
  ]
});
```

So I have an array of devices which is just a list 12-byte hashes like: `AB4576D4C6AC`, etc.

I am looping through the device array and assembling my "fake" log entry like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    var timeStmp = startDateTime.clone().add((i * config.dsmIntervalMinutes), "m");
    dsm = {
        deviceId: devices[i].deviceId,
        msg: "some log entry text",
        timeStmp: timeStmp
    };
    logger.info(dsm);
}
```

As you can see, I end by logging the message as `info` to Winston after each DSM is created in the loop.

So this seems to work fine, except when I have a large number of devices. I want to get up to 1m devices or so. I am currently struggling to do 100k.

What I see is that the node process is not writing the logs to the log file. It seems to be storing them all in memory (as seen by using `top`) and once it gets to 10k or so it slows to a crawl and eventually stops progressing. The log file is never written.

So I am wondering if there is a way to do this? Can I somehow force node/winston to stop and write to disk every once in a while? Like flush the cache? I don't see options in winston for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried 

for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    process.nextTick(function(){
    var timeStmp = startDateTime.clone().add((i * config.dsmIntervalMinutes), "m");
    dsm = {
        deviceId: devices[i].deviceId,
        msg: "some log entry text",
        timeStmp: timeStmp
    };
    logger.info(dsm);
    });
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't quite that the loop is synchronous, it's that you need to stop writing to the underlying `fs.createWriteStream` instance when it is flushing to disk. By not waiting you continue to fill up the internal buffer which is why your memory usage is increasing without bound.

So with that in mind, the code sample becomes:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var winston = require('winston');

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('logs/dsm.log');
var file = new (winston.transports.File)({ stream: stream });
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({ transports: [file] });

//
// We'll store this for our position in all devices across
// `drain` events from the stream.
//
var curr = 0;

//
// function isFlushing()
// Returns a value if the file is flushing
//
function isFlushing() {
  var state = stream._writeableState;
  return state.length < state.highWaterMark;
}

//
// function logDevice()
// Logs a single device and returns a value
// indicating if the underlying filestream is full.
//
function logDevice(d) {
  var timeStmp = startDateTime.clone().add((i * config.dsmIntervalMinutes), 'm');  
  logger.info({
    deviceId: d.deviceId,
    msg: 'some log entry text',
    timeStmp: timeStmp
  });

  return isFlushing();
}

(function logAllDevices() {
  for (; curr < devices.length; curr++) {
    if (!logDevice(devices[curr])) {
      stream.once('drain', logAllDevices);
      break;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Truly appreciated! I am having trouble with the `isFlushing()` function. It returns an exception `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I am looking into the `stream._writeableState` via google but if you had an idea, awesome ;)

Comment: I cannot get isFlushing() working. I tried a number if things like getBuffer() and _writeableState.buffer

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're using a for loop. Node.js (the JavaScript layer) is single threaded. Your for loop is blocking the process from actually getting to the write phase.

Change it to something like this so you loop over the devices without suffocating the process:

```
function doLog (d, cb) {
    var timeStmp = startDateTime.clone().add((i * config.dsmIntervalMinutes), "m");
    dsm = {
        deviceId: d.deviceId,
        msg: "some log entry text",
        timeStmp: timeStmp
    };
    // Callback is fired once the write is complete
    logger.info(dsm, cb);
}

async.eachSeries(devices, doLog, function () {
  log.info('Finished!')
});
```

The async module will basically run each operation in order one after the other (eachSeries) and internally use setImmediate to defer each call to allow I/O before starting the next device doLog call. You could also look into async.parallelLimit to do a few at the same time to get better performance.

Comment: thx so much @eshortie I knew it had to do with async vs. sync, I just didn't know how to solve it. I have not used `async` before. Thanks for putting me onto that ;) One last question, what is the difference between `async.each()` and `async.eachSeries()`? I googled it but didn't find much and the async docs don't go into it.

Comment: No problem. async.eachSeries runs the given function one after the other an Array of items. async.each will run the function for each item at the same time. One caveat; async.each assumes that the function run e.g doLog is asynchronous, if it's not then naturally the operations won't truly be run in parallel but rather as soon as they can be completed. The callback async injects into your doLog function is a way to say "hey this one is done, do the next or call the final callback" for eachSeries for each it's "hey this is done, check are we done everything and if so fire the final callback"

Comment: actually @eshortie I may have spoken too soon. The above works on a small number of devices but if I crank it up to say 10000 or more, I observe that each log entry is not being written out sequentially but they are kept in memory (the stack climbs and climbs) and then written out to disk at the end. Interestingly, the eachSeries() callback is called, but the actual writes are not yet finished and my app doesn't actually end until they are finished. Any ideas why async.eachSeries() is not forcing the writes in every iteration?

Comment: That would be to do with the underlying implementation used in winston. I updated my answer to help, winston log methods take a callback that is fired once the write is complete so pass cb to the log method.